# sikuliとPythonを使いデータを読込みたいです

Tags: python

仕事上今までプログラムを触ったことがない私がプログラムを作成することになり
行き詰っております。
全くの初心者の為、至らない点もありますがご教示をお願いいたします。

環境
Windows10
office2016
SikuliIDE1.1.1

やりたいこと
時間とともにエクセルファイルが更新されるため都度データをPythonで読み込み
forで回し、if関数を使いながら場合分け作業を行いたいです。

Pythonで処理
B列が空白の場合→pass
B列が「確認済み」の場合→C列に記載がされているか確認
記載がされていなかったらB列の英数字をコピー

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import sys
import xlwt
import xlrd
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
FILEDIR = u"C:\\Users\\xxxxxxx\\Desktop\\test\\"
FILENAME_R = u"ExcelDataSample.xlsx"
FILENAME_W1 = u"ExcelDataSample_w1.xls"
FILENAME_W2 = u"ExcelDataSample_w2.xls"
book_r = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\xxxxxxx\\Desktop\\質問用.xlsx')
sheet1 = book_r.sheet_by_index(0)
print(book_r.nsheets)
print(sheet1.nrows)
print(sheet1.ncols)
print('----------------------------')
min_row = 1
max_row = 4
min_col = 1
max_col = 4
for num in range(min_row,max_row+1):
 data = sheet1.cell(num,1).value
if data is None:
 pass
if data is 確認済み:
 for num in range(min_row,max_row+1):
  data2 = sheet1.cell(num,2).value
   if data2 is None:
       data3 = sheet1.cell(num,0).value 
        print(data3)
```

以上です。

エラーは下記が出るのですが
全角で入力しているところもなくsikuliの左の行欄にもエラー行の表示はありません

> [error] Error caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create PyString with non-byte value

「if data is 確認済み:」の前まではエラーもなにも表示されず進めました。
しかし細かいエラーが記載されていないため
どこが誤っているか見当もつきません。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/120601

Comment: 断片でも構わないのでご自身で書いたコードを提示することは出来ませんか？「プログラムの書き方」は覚えてもらうしかなく、この質問文だと「要件定義をしたので、誰か代わりにプログラム書いてください」という印象を与えます。具体的なコードを挙げながら「ここが意図した通り動かない」といった質問になると、回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。全部書くとごちゃごちゃになりそうですので一つずつ解決していこうと思います。

Answer (score 2):

次の行は文法的に間違っているので、

```
if data is 確認済み
```

以下のように修正してみてください

```
if data == '確認済み':
```

Python2系を使っているようなので、それでうまくいかない場合は、次のようにしてみます。

```
if data == u'確認済み':
```